# How to count or sum fields if only if the current field exists in an array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mongodb

I have the following query :

```
SELECT 
count(form_rows.field_name), 
form_rows.field_name, 
sum(form_rows.field_value) as sales, 
form_Submissions.id as fsId 
FROM form_submissions
LEFT JOIN form_rows on form_Submissions.id = form_rows.form_submission_id
WHERE form_submissions.organization_id = 10
GROUP BY form_rows.field_name
```

That reproduces the following results:
[image]

**QUESTION:** Is there any way to `SUM` and `COUNT` based on `field_name`

**Clarification:**

Say I have an array: `["ssn", "price"]`

I want to sum only  `sales` that `field_names` are present in given array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this not do it:

```
SELECT 
count(form_rows.field_name), 
form_rows.field_name, 
sum(form_rows.field_value) as sales, 
form_Submissions.id as fsId 
FROM form_submissions
LEFT JOIN form_rows on form_Submissions.id = form_rows.form_submission_id
WHERE form_submissions.organization_id = 10

AND form_rows.field_names in ('ssn','price')

GROUP BY form_rows.field_name
```

Comment: awesome, I totally forgot about that option! As this is just a subquery in monster query.